Redirection Issue in Kotlin
I am working on a beginner-level quiz project where I am using Firebase Authentication for login and signup, Firebase Database for storing quiz data, and the Material Design 3 Date Picker for date selection.
The problem is that I am being redirected to QuestionActivity after data is fetched from the Firebase Database, instead of being redirected based on the date selected.
I have implemented code to ensure that redirection occurs only when a specific date is selected, but despite following the suggested debugging steps, the issue persists.
QuestionActivity.kt:
package com.somethingelse.quiz2

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.somethingelse.quiz2.adapters.OptionAdapter
import com.somethingelse.quiz2.databinding.ActivityQuestionBinding
import com.somethingelse.quiz2.models.Questions
import com.somethingelse.quiz2.models.Quiz

class QuestionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityQuestionBinding
    private var quizzes : MutableList<Quiz>? = null
    private var questions : MutableMap<String, Questions>? = null
    var index = 1


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        binding = ActivityQuestionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setUpFirestore()


        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }

    private fun setUpFirestore() {
        val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val date = intent.getStringExtra("DATE")
        if (date != null) {
            firestore.collection("questions").whereEqualTo("title", date)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    if(it != null && !it.isEmpty){
                        quizzes = it.toObjects(Quiz::class.java)
                        questions = quizzes!![0].questions
                        bindViews()
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private fun bindViews() {
        // Example static question setup. Replace this with dynamic data as needed.
        val question = Questions(
            "Which is the only bird that can fly backwards",
            "Sunbird",
            "Kingfisher",
            "Honey eater",
            "Hummingbird",
            "Hummingbird"
        )
        binding.description.text = question.description
        val optionAdapter = OptionAdapter(this, question)
        binding.optionList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.optionList.adapter = optionAdapter
        binding.optionList.setHasFixedSize(true) // Note the corrected method name
    }
}

DrawerLayout.kt:
package com.somethingelse.quiz2

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.somethingelse.quiz2.adapters.QuizAdapter
import com.somethingelse.quiz2.databinding.ActivityDrawerLayoutBinding
import com.somethingelse.quiz2.models.Quiz
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Locale

class DrawerLayout : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDrawerLayoutBinding
    private lateinit var actionBarDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
    private lateinit var firestore: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var adapter: QuizAdapter
    private var quizList = mutableListOf<Quiz>()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        binding = ActivityDrawerLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupViews()


        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }


    private fun setupViews() {
        setUpFireStore()
        setupDrawerLayout()
        setupRecyclerView()
        setupDatePicker()
    }

    private fun setupDatePicker() {
        binding.btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener {
            val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
                .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_DatePicker)
                .build()

            datePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "DATEPICKER")
            datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
                val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.UK)
                val date = dateFormatter.format(Date(it))
                val intent = Intent(this, QuestionActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("DATE", date)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            datePicker.addOnNegativeButtonClickListener {
                Log.d("DATEPICKER", datePicker.headerText)
            }

            datePicker.addOnCancelListener {
                Log.d("DATEPICKER", "Date Picker Cancelled")
            }
        }
    }


    private fun setUpFireStore() {
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val collectionReference = firestore.collection("questions")
        collectionReference.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if(value == null || error != null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error fetching data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            Log.d("DATA", value.toObjects(Quiz::class.java).toString())
            quizList.clear()
            quizList.addAll(value.toObjects(Quiz::class.java))
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }


    private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        adapter = QuizAdapter(this, quizList)
        binding.quizRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
        binding.quizRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun setupDrawerLayout() {
        setSupportActionBar(binding.topAppBar)
        actionBarDrawerToggle =
            ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, binding.main, R.string.open_nav, R.string.close_nav)
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}


I removed the Date Picker, but the issue remains unresolved.
I removed the setUpFirestore function from DrawerLayout, and as a result, the data was not fetched.
I removed the setUpFirestore function from QuestionActivity, but the redirection issue persists.
I have reviewed the code thoroughly but did not identify any issues.


Have you tried to get the data from Firestore after the selection in the DatePicker is made?
